# Delaying gradient update in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Minibatch gradient descent is roughly as follows. Let `B` be set of mini-batches, `w` be network weights, `l` be learning rate, `g()` be gradient function. SGD algorithm is:

```
for b in B:
    w = w - l * g(b, w)
```

At each epoch, `g` is a noisy observation of the gradient. What I want to experiment with is a "model averaging approach" where I calculate the average noisy gradient then make the update at the end (mine is a regression problem).

```
g_m = np.zeros(w.shape)
i = 0
for b in B:
    g_m = (g_m * i + g(b, w)) / (i + 1)

w = w - l * g_m
```

Is there a way of getting the gradient only in Keras?